# How to move js file dynamically to pub/static folder in Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta

I created custom module with requirejs-config.js and js folder 
when ever page loads requirejs-config is dynamically created in `pub/static/_requirejs` folder, but my custom JS is not created automatically i need to copy paste manually in my local system

Do magento2  have any command to build `pub/static` JS files or  manually we need to move into `pub\static\frontend\Magento\luma\en_US\MYNAME_MYMODULE\js`

i tried below command but not working

```
bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, please ensure that you module properly installed.

If you work in developer mode, files materialized by request, so no needs in any command.
`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` need only for production mode, where assume that filesystem readonly (see: [docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html)). To identify with mode you use, you can run command `bin/magento deploy:mode:show`

See more details in [official documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html)

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 copies the browser resources (JavaScript, CSS) to the pub/static folder automatically without any console commands.
If your files have not been copied, then you did something wrong. Maybe, you placed the files in a wrong location. Use a core module as an example and do carefully the same.